# Subqueries Condition (SQL)

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, conditional-statements

So i want to create a view using the below script the problem is i want to show the view for 2020 grouped by quarter as you can see i have 2 subqueries using `to_char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYY') = 2020` I want to return quarter results **ONLY** if `FileNO`'s in both subqueries are from the Same Quarter.

```
    SELECT Quarter,
    count(FileNO), avg(total_time),
    sum( case when Total_Time <= :T Then 1 Else 0 End ) Achieved,
    sum( case when Total_Time <= :T Then 1 Else 0 End ) / Count(FileNO) * 100 Precentage_Acheived
from 
 (SELECT to_Char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYYQ') as Quarter, FileNO, SUM(work_time) as total_time
    FROM F.MV
   WHERE 
   (FileNO, APP_no) IN
                 (SELECT FileNO, APP_no
                    FROM F.MV
                   WHERE    to_char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYY') = 2020
                            AND TASK_NAME = 'Lifting'
                            AND TO_TASK_NAME = 'Finish')
        AND DEPT_NAME = 'TempDep'
        AND WF_TASK_NAME = 'Lifting'
        and to_char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYY') = 2020
GROUP BY to_Char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYYq'),FileNO
)
GROUP BY Quarter
```

Correct if i use `to_char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYYQ') = 20201` for both subquieres
[image]

but result iam getting with `to_char(ACTION_DATE,'YYYY') = 2020` is:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the innermost correlation clause you want is:

```
(FileNO, APP_no) IN
             (SELECT mv2.FileNO, mv2.APP_no
              FROM F.MV mv2
              WHERE to_char(mv2.ACTION_DATE, 'YYYYQ') = to_char(mv.ACTION_DATE, 'YYYYQ')
```